# Swap element during drag - jquery ui

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, drag, jquery-ui-draggable

I want swap element during drag. Example, When I'm dragging the red box into the container with the blue box, the blue box in that container will turn into a red box, and the red box i'm dragging will turn into a blue box. Then I will continue to drag the blue box away. All is the drag process.

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child" id="child1"></div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child" id="child2"></div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
</div>
```

Js:

```
$("document").ready(function() {
  $(".child").draggable({
    /* revert: true */
  });
  $(".parent").droppable({
    //accept: '.child',
    drop: function(event, ui) {
    },
    over: function(event, ui) {
      if ($(this).children().length > 0) {
        $(ui.draggable).html($(this).children());
      }
      $(this).html(ui.draggable);
    },
  });
});
```

The result is not what I expected. You can see demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/lion5893/845ybwLs/23/

Comment: 1) I do not see a "red" box in your example 2) You can't really do that. So during drag, you can use `over` callback to manipulate the helper or draggable yet it's best to not change out the element itself. Plus you're not swapping them in your code, but nesting one into the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a function like:

```
function dragSwap(a, b) {
  var id1 = a.attr("id");
  var id2 = b.attr("id");
  b.attr("id", id1);
  a.attr("id", id2);
}
```

Looking at your code, the elements are the same, both `<div>`, the classes the same etc, the only difference is the `id`.

You might have something like this:

```
over: function(event, ui) {
  if ($(this).children().length > 0 && $(this).children().length == 1) {
    var item = $(this).children().eq(0);
    var drag = ui.draggable;
    dragSwap(item, drag);
  }
}
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/y285a4bq/

Hope that helps.